# Book Chapter Decoration

Tags: decorations

How can I produce the following decoration, meant to be used in the chapters of a book?

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the `pgfornament` package? It has tons of beautiful ornaments that can be used as decorations. Alain Matthes, the package author, is one of the users here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes I have checked all the decorations in that package and also in the `psvectorian` one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `adforn` package has two variants:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great! How do I scale them though? The package's manual doesn't specify a way, which is unusual for such a package.

Comment: Changing locally the font size? Or `\scalebox` (with moderate factor!)?

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the opentype `Minion Pro` font (which comes with Acrobat Reader) has a similar glyph in its ‘Private Use Area’. Of course, this requires the installation of the `MinionPro` package to use it with LaTeX.